# How to retrieve urlencoded name for cookie

Tags: php

I am building a small website that sets a cookie which may have special characters in the name.  I used `rawurlencode()` before setting the cookie with `setrawcookie()`.  When I check in the browser developer tools, it shows the cookie with the characters properly encoded (for example space is %20).  The problem is that the value in `$_COOKIE` is urldecoded and therefore spaces and dots are turned into underscores.  How can I get the cookie value as it is truly sent to the server?

Thanks

Comment: %20 is not a "proper" encoding in a url. urlencode() turns `space` into `+`. `rawurlencode()`, however, would produce a `%20`

Comment: Maybe you should think about naming your cookies different. I don't see a reason why a cookie's name should contain a space. Although this is no solution for your problem, it may prohibit further problems in the future with third party software etc.

Comment: Mark, you're right I am using rawurlencode() not urlencode(). Sorry.

Comment: @Tokk The cookie is set when the user inputs a password to access a certain page on the site. The page needs to be able to have spaces in its name. Should I work around it by not storing the page name in the cookie name? Perhaps by having the name be the random ID that I currently store as the value?

Comment: I think that a random ID would be better because a user could find out, he can change the cookie to the pages name and gain access. With a random ID this will not happen.

Comment: @Tokk I already had the random ID stored as the value (so it was required along with the page name), but I went ahead and switched it around to store them in the name and then just a simple "1" in the value.  It just checks that that cookie exists and if so gives them appropriate access.  This seems to be working great now, thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

You can see the cookies sent by the browser using `$_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']`.

Comment: While this might get you the raw value, I don't think it's a good idea to use this. It's [**not** documented](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php), so it's probably not reliable.

Comment: While that does work and I've played around with it a little bit, it seems to return them as a string not an array so how would I extract the cookie value from that?  Also as Amal says, it isn't documented and I've seen others cautioning against using it because of this reason.

Comment: While the concerns are legitimate, and, the best solution would be to name your cookies differently without needing to encode them etc... this method has been working without issues for more than a decade. To get them into an array just explode the string at the semi-colon, then loop through the results and explode those at the equals sign into a list, etc... lots of ways you could do this.